# make synchronous HTTP calls in Angular 11

Tags: angular, typescript, rest

I created a service to get product details from product id like the following:

```
public async getXeViaId(id_xe:string)
{
  const path =`${this.apiServerURL}/xe/get_xe_via_id?id_product=${id_xe}`;
  const result = this.http.get(path).toPromise();
  return result;
}
```

Then I test like the following

```
this.xeService.getXeViaId("XE1700000082").then(value=>{console.log(value)});
```

Then it work fine but when I try with for loop like the following:

```
cart:any[]=[]
for(let i =0;i<3;++i)
    {
      let product:any
      this.xeService.getXeViaId("XE1700000082").then(value=>{product=value});
      this.cart.push(product)
    }
```

When I debug I realize that the `cart`  push value null,its meaning value of product that I received is null.

How I can wait until HTTP request of one for loop is finished and then push it to cart. I tried to solve it using Promise and many way that use Promise to solve that problem but none of them worked fine.
Can you guys fix it help me.It take a lot of my time

Comment: You might like `async`/`await`

Comment: Yeah I did like you say,but the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const cart = [];
for(let i =0;i<3;++i) {
  cart.push(
    await this.xeService.getXeViaId("XE1700000082")
  );
}
```

Comment: I try like you did for me but it not working , please help me

Comment: @Dunguyen this is not helpful feedback. Please elaborate. I can't help you if you don't share any detail.

Comment: async ngOnInit(){
    
    for(let i =0;i<3;++i)
    {
      let product:any;
      product = await this.xeService.getXeViaId("XE1700000082")
      this.cart_t.push(product)
    }

Comment: @Dunguyen this doesn't tell me anything. Try explaining the problem. All I know so far is that 'it's not working'

Comment: I test it by put your code inside `ngOnInit()` function ,but it show the same error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of null`

Comment: Well, that's the first time you're saying you got an error. Try creating `this.cart` before pushing data in it.

Comment: @Dunguyen that cannot be true if you did it correctly. I don't think I can help you here further. I believe I solved your original problem, but I can't walk you through writing code until you have a working application. Please accept my answer

Comment: because the error show that `Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of null`.I think may be it is my service  So do you have any change in my service?

Comment: @Dunguyen  I can't help you debug your entire application. If you initialized the array before pushing you would not get that error. Please accept my answer and open a new question if you have additional questions.

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing a null because you do not wait the end of the execution of your promise.

You need to use async/await to achieve this.

```
const cart = [];
for(let i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
  cart.push(
    await this.xeService.getXeViaId("XE1700000082")
  );
}
```

And don't forget to add async on your calling method.